# Using Active_record-acts_as as a many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Here's the example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  actable
  belongs_to :store
end

class Pen < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :product
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as :product
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

I have multiple stores and I would like to keep Pens and Books even if they don't belong to a store.

My first issue is when I add a Pen to a store (via product) the store isn't set in the product table

```
store.products << pen
```

This created a `product` entity, but doesn't add the `store_id`.

Secondly, I would like to be able to delete the product without deleting the pen. Currently both product and pen are deleted.

EDIT: Here's what I'm getting in the terminal

```
 SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("actable_id", "actable_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["actable_id", 25], ["actable_type", "Pen"], ["created_at", "2016-08-17 10:05:24.947018"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-17 10:05:24.947018"]]
```

There's no mention of trying to save the Store

Thanks

Comment: Your `store` is a new object or existing object?

Comment: It will always be an existing Pen or Book

Comment: I meant `store` variable holding a new `Store` or existing `Store` object?

Comment: Oh, I am calling it on an existing store object

Comment: ok, then it should set the `store_id` in Product table.

Comment: Any ideas on why it's not doing that?